# What exactly is required to test?

Tags: gmail, google-schemas

According to the docs (https://developers.google.com/gmail/actions/testing-your-schema), you can test by sending an email from yourself to yourself. I'm doing that via a local test on my machine using an application server to connect to GMail SMTP and send the email. I get the email. I've also verified my embedded JSON with the Email markup tester here (https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-tester/), but I can never get the card to show up in Google Now.

But - if I use Apps Scripting it does work.

So am I confused about what is required to test? As I said, it clearly points out that you can send it from you, to you, and my code passes the validation, but cards do NOT show up when running my code locally.

If folks want to see it, here is a Gist with the ColdFusion code. Password is modded of course. And to be clear, I'm definitely getting the emails.

https://gist.github.com/cfjedimaster/6826259

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A proper DKIM/SPF signature is also required in order to prevent spoofing.

Besides, Google Now has additional requirements for a card to show up. For instance, the event time must be close to the current time.

Comment: The event time makes sense, but I'd argue that the DKIM/SPF thing is a bug in that it isn't documented. I think folks testing on a local machine (sending emails from them and to them) is a typical use case, but in this case you *can't* do it because of this undocumented requirement. Right?

Comment: And more so (and I realize this isn't your decision of course :) why is spoofing even a concern here? I'm sending email from me to me. That requirement right there should be enough I'd warrant.

Comment: I'll make sure this is better documented. Spoofing is a concern because someone can send you an email that looks like it's coming from yourself and we don't want to show spammy actions.

Comment: Fair enough. Didn't know you were on the team. Thanks for the prompt help!

Comment: does it requires both DKIM/SPF?, for the action button to appear, because I get mailed-by : gmail.com but not signed by details and of course the action button doesn't appear

Comment: Either DKIM or SPF is required